# Simply listening music by folders?

Tags: music

I'm currently fighting both rhythmbox and banshee for an easy way to just browse and play my music by folders. I don't want to create stupid playlists. 
And seems that there is no way?

Comment: Both, Rhythmbox and Banshee, use a Music Library, sorted by Artist/Album. Probably Clementine would be a more suitable Player for your purpose, since it has a folder browser Tab on the left side (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 2):

I also prefer to listen my music by folder and use VLC media player for this purpose.  To select a folder to play you simply press Ctrl+F - nothing fancy, but works great for this purpose.